# Is there an analytic function whose imaginary (or real) part 1) equals zero on the real axis 2) equals 1 on the imaginary axis?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

The boundary conditions must only be satisfied in the first quadrant. I don't know how to even start to solve this problem, since non of my originally thought simple analytic functions satisfied these conditions. I also can't think of a conformal transformation that would make the problem simpler.

Comment: Imaginary part of $f$ is a continuous function. It cannot be $0$ on the real axis and $1$ on the imaginary axis because that violates continuity at $0$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it equals 1 on the imaginary axis for $y>0$

Comment: That still violates continuity at $0$.

Comment: the function won't be continuous on the boundary, but if it is enough that $\Re f$ has the boundary limits mentioned (say non tangentially) then one can have such a function

Comment: Yes, it is enough. I am not sure how to find such a function.